# com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.compressassetsworkaction

Tags: unity, android, video

When I build with asset size of above 5gb, it shows **"com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.compressassetsworkaction"** in unity. How to resolve it?. It's a video file. When I use low resolution file, it works fine. Is that any way to build an apk without compressing video file?

Comment: Aren't Android asset packs limited to 4GB max? If your video doesn't compress to less than that, you may need to chop it into smaller pieces and play the pieces back-to-back.